# appending decrypted Text to JTextArea

Tags: java, encryption, aes, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Problem: appending encrypted text in JTextArea

Objective: trying to get the chosen file with JFileCHooser call 'decrypt' method and then take the output back to the original method(decryptArea) All code is below.

Question: Why won't this work? I don't understand because we are working with File's should this not go through and decrypt the file and append it. I have a normal method that does the exact same thing except doesn't decrypt of course (normal save file and open file method) just trying to put the pieces together it would be unfortunate to not know what I'm doing wrong and then end up redesigning when there is no need

userFieled = JTextArea();***********

```
private void decryptArea() throws Exception {
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
  fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
  int dialog = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

  if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    inputDec = fc.getSelectedFile();
    inputDec.getName();
    inputDec.getAbsoluteFile();
    inputDec = fc.getSelectedFile();

    userField.append("");
    System.out.println(" File: " + inputDec);




   File fd = new File (inputDec.getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath());
     FileReader reader = new FileReader(fd);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
     userField.read(br,null);

     br.close();
     userField.requestFocus();


  // userField.append(inputDec);
    userField.requestFocus();

    System.out.println("Finished appending decrypted text:");
  }

}  
    });
```

// Where the decrypting is going on

```
public void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile, byte[] key) throws Exception {
       Cipher cipher = getCipherDecrypt(key);
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       CipherInputStream cis = null;
       FileInputStream fis = null;
       try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
           cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
           fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
           byte[] data = new byte[1024];
           int read = cis.read(data);
           while (read != -1) {
           fos.write(data, 0, read);
           read = cis.read(data);
           System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());
           }
       } finally {
           cis.close();
           fos.close();
           fis.close();
       }
}
```

Comment: What is `userField`?

Comment: Do you actually read the file? As in, load it into memory? If so, where?

Comment: From what Im understanding from my point of view atleast; its being passed into decrypt method and then 'outputFile' should be coming back up to decryptArea and then would go through the rest of the code there thats what I'm not understanding. But the file itself when its encrypted is being saved to... Desktop or whatever directory the user chooses